# How to convert decimals amount to eth?

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethereumjs, ethers.js

From a subgraph I'm getting my total debt as: 1000148245, how can I convert this value to eth decimals?

Comment: When you say "subgraph" what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

`1000148245` is a representation in [wei](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/w/wei.asp).

To display amount in UI, you can divide it using 10<sup>18</sup>. In ethers.js there is a method that helps you do that:

```
import { ethers } from 'ethers';

ethers.utils.formatEther('1000148245'); // gives "0.000000001000148245"
```